# Gradle compile error with same module

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

i am trying to import 2 Libraries with Gradle.

When i am importing one of them its working but when i compile both i get the exception below.

I am working with Android Studio.

Getting the exception below:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/bouncycastle/crypto/CipherParameters.class

and my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')


compile ('org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.50') {
    exclude module: 'bcpkix-jdk15on' // Excluded to prevent cyclic dependencies
}

compile ('org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.50') {
    exclude module: 'bcprov-jdk15on' // Excluded to prevent cyclic dependencies
}
```

}

Thanks

Marvin

Comment: Perhaps because one of those allready include the other one. So it's like you try to import twice time the same library which could explain "duplicate entry".

Comment: Yes, i found my mistake now, android is already using a cut down version of bouncy castle. It worked with com.madgag.spongycastle. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android is already using a cut down version of bouncy castle. It worked with com.madgag.spongycastle.